# JRules setup problem

Tags: eclipse, configuration, internal, jrules

Been getting to grips with JRules doing the tutorials. During part 5 of the 2nd tutorial it ask's you to run the rules via RetePlus using the cmds

On the Run menu, click Run. 
In the Run dialog, select the Rule Project launch configuration ruleediting-start-configuration. 
Click Run.

However everytime I try to run it I get a pop up box telling me an internal error occurred during: "launching"

No other real output.

I have imported the completed tutorial and it gives the same error so that is suggesting that it would be configuration problem. I have changed the runtime JRE.

Has anyone encoutered this in either in JRules or Eclipse

**EDIT**

I did manage to get the Exception stack Trace:

Stack Trace
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.setDocumentInfo(DOM2TO.java:373)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:127)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:94)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:661)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:707)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
at ilog.rules.archive.IlrRulesetArchiveBuilderBase$XmlBase.writeDocumentInternal(Unknown Source)
at ilog.rules.archive.IlrRulesetArchiveBuilderBase$XmlBase.access$000(Unknown Source)
at ilog.rules.archive.IlrRulesetArchiveBuilderBase$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at ilog.rules.archive.IlrRulesetArchiveBuilderBase$XmlBase.writeDocument(Unknown Source)
at ilog.rules.archive.IlrRulesetArchiveBuilderBase$XmlBase.write(Unknown Source)
at ilog.rules.archive.IlrRulesetArchiveBuilderBase.xmlEntry(Unknown Source)
at ilog.rules.archive.IlrRulesetArchiveBuilderBase.fillMetadata(Unknown Source)
at ilog.rules.archive.IlrRulesetArchiveBuilderBase.fillResources(Unknown Source)
at ilog.rules.archive.IlrRulesetArchiveBuilderBase.fillArchive(Unknown Source)
at ilog.rules.engine.IlrRulesetArchiveBuilder.fillArchive(Unknown Source)
at ilog.rules.archive.IlrRulesetArchiveBuilderBase.generateArchive(Unknown Source)
at ilog.rules.archive.IlrRulesetArchiveBuilderBase.generate(Unknown Source)
at ilog.rules.studio.model.archive.IlrRulesetArchiveExporter.export(Unknown Source)
at ilog.rules.studio.launching.IlrProjectLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:639)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:565)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:754)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$6.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:944)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:58)

Session Data
eclipse.buildId=M20070212-1330
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -perspective ilog.rules.studio.ui.perspectives.RuleEditingPerspective
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -perspective ilog.rules.studio.ui.perspectives.RuleEditingPerspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JRE issue reinstalled the software with bundled JRE and it worked. Must be an issue with using the 1.6 JDK as its compiler.